# GDAL Brightness RGB Contrast Gamma Saturation

Tags: gdal, imagery

I've not had much experience with modifying imagery, I've recently been playing with GDAL for some batch processing of geo-referenced images, I've been supplied with some imagery in ECW format that is rather dull and could do with some RGB, Contrast Gamma and Saturation adjustments.

Is it possible to adjust these values using GDAL or something similar?

I have managed to find the following values would most benefit my imagery.

```
Brightness -5
R 0
G +5
B -5
Contrast +75
Gamma +2.0
Saturation +190
```

This was found using irfanview which when used to batch process the imagery seems to strip the georeferenced inforamtion from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageenhance.htm). There are lots of function for image processing.

With pil you can control Brightness, Contrast... for gamma read [Gamma Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904908/430408)...
and you can look for image manipulation [image.py](http://www.koders.com/python/fid798D591F71AC2C5F462B7BFFF0D84E1EA8D5759F.aspx?s=timer)